# Debian and docking station

Tags: debian, xfce, hp, dock-station

I am really despred, becouse I can't get my laptop and my docking station to work. Is there any kind of magic that I forgot ? I have HP elitebook 650 G1 and basic HP docking station. I have fresh install so I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. I am running Debian Jessie with these GPUs (I installed drivers only for AMD GPU). Oh and I have Xfce.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
```

Comment: What is a basic GP docking station? Does it have a name or number?

Comment: Product: A7E32AA